# How to get current record id in odoo 14 js

Tags: javascript, odoo

I save the current record using

```
$(".o_form_button_save").click();
```

Now I want to get the record id of this record. While printing "this", I am not able to find the id.

Answer (score 0):

So for that you have to setup your event handler to call a function when event "click" arise . I think you should extend the FormView to do this in a clean manner.

Here is some pseudo code

```
FormView.extend({
      events: {
          'click #target button': 'button_clicked',
      },      
      
      button_clicked: function(ev) {   
        
         //your logic
          var field_values = this.get_fields_values();
          var id = field_values['id']
          });
```

Hope this helps, please inform me of the result !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for solution, try this :

```
var ExtendFormController = FormController.include({

events: {
       "click.get_id_button": "getID",
    },

getID: function (ev){
    console.log('Button Clicked')

    var recordID = Object.values(this.model.localData)[0]["data"]['id']
    console.log(recordID)


},

});
```

reference in comments :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLbjhlXqt98